# Override edit functionality Devise, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, overriding, edit

I was trying to override devise default edit method. Normally, by default, it can only edit current_user. But I want to edit any user I want. That's why I coded like this:
IN CONTROLLER:

```
  def edit
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

And it is called from the show, where I called this function like this:
SHOW.HTML.ERB:

```
<%= link_to user_profiles_edit_path(@user.id) do%>
          <button class="btn btn-info">Edit Profile</button>
        <% end %>
```

And in edit, I had a form, which starts like this:
EDIT.HTML.ERB:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <table class="table table-striped">

      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:first_name, :class=>"full-width-input") %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:last_name, :class=>"full-width-input") %></td>
      </tr>
...
...
...
```

And I added this line in my routes.rb:
ROUTES.RB

```
   get "/users/:id/edit/" => "users/registrations#edit",:as =>"user_profiles_edit"
```

But, After doing all these, I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f3da064c050>:0x007f3da065adf8>
Did you mean?  users_path
```

Comment: Not a good idea - override a devise controller to do things for which it is not intended. Better option here would be to write a separate UsersController and add all CRUD actions there

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the advice. Almost similar thing done.